# Object scale is already 1.0 but apply scale always increases object size

Tags: objects

Object scaling is already X: 1.0/Y: 1.0/Z: 1.0. Why is Object -> Apply -> Scale increasing the dimensions of the object? Also when I apply scale again, it still increases the size. So where does this scale come from, if it does not come from these scale values shown?

[image: N -> Transform -> Scale already 1.0 before Apply -> Scale]